# search in array of array, and return results in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, indexof

using the following array of arrays I need to make a search by letter, if it finds that element it should return in one array

example

```
const data= [[
      "car",
      "plane",
      "boat"
  ],
  [
      "cartago",
      "barcelona",
      "los angeles"
  ],
  [
      "headphone",
      "phone",
      "camera",
  ]
]
```

if match "ca" must return

```
[car, cartago, camera]
```

if match "ne" must return

```
[plane, headphone, phone]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question. SO isn't a code-writing forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flat the array and filter it by checking if the substring is included in each element

```js
const data= [[      "car",      "plane",      "boat"  ],  [      "cartago",      "barcelona",      "los angeles"  ],  [      "headphone",      "phone",      "camera",  ]]

let a = data.flat().filter(v => v.includes('ca'))
console.log(a)

let b = data.flat().filter(v => v.includes('ne'))
console.log(b)
```

Comment: You can use .map() and spread (...) the values, is faster.

Comment: @ElvisPimentel didnt quite get you.

Comment: const data= [["car", "plane", "boat"],["cartago","barcelona","los angeles"],["headphone","phone","camera",]];
const matches = [];
const pattern = 'ca';
data.map(item => matches.push(...item.filter(s => s.includes(pattern))));